# jQuery slide content on radio check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I'm trying to make a small jQuery function to hide & show content when a radio button is checked. The script works but when the radio button is checked the content is not showing right. It's possible to make effect to slide out then slide in the other content?

HTML:

```
<!-- Section class pricing -->
<section class="pricing">
    <div class="container">
        <hr class="hr">
        <!-- Price table switcher -->
        <div class="table-switcher" id="btn">
            <p class="fieldset">
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="duration" value="account-1" id="account-1">
                <label for="account-1">1</label>
                <input type="radio" name="duration" value="account-2" id="account-2">
                <label for="account-2">2</label>
                <span class="btn-switch"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Price table switcher end -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- Info box -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="accounts container">
        <div class="price-table">
            <!-- Account Plus -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- Table -->
                    <div class="account-1 account-box">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-6">
                        <li class="plan">Basic</li>
                            <li class="plan-cost">$99k</li>
                            <li class="plan-duration">Per Month</li>
                            <li>Use on One Site</li>
                            <li>Feature Two</li>
                            <li>Another Great Feature</li>
                            <li class="plan-button"><a href="#">Get Started &raquo;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Table end -->
                    <!-- Table -->

                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-6">
                            <li class="plan">Basic</li>
                            <li class="plan-cost">$99</li>
                            <li class="plan-duration">Per Month</li>
                            <li>Use on One Site</li>
                            <li>Feature Two</li>
                            <li>Another Great Feature</li>
                            <li class="plan-button"><a href="#">Get Started &raquo;</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    <!-- Table end -->
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Account Plus end -->

            <!-- Account O€ -->
            <div class="account-2 account-box">
                <!-- Table -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="plan">Basic</li>
                        <li class="plan-cost">$99</li>
                        <li class="plan-duration">Per Month</li>
                        <li>Use on One Site</li>
                        <li>Feature Two</li>
                        <li>Another Great Feature</li>
                        <li class="plan-button"><a href="#">Get Started &raquo;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Table end -->
                <!-- Table -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="plan">Basic</li>
                        <li class="plan-cost">$99</li>
                        <li class="plan-duration">Per Month</li>
                        <li>Use on One Site</li>
                        <li>Feature Two</li>
                        <li>Another Great Feature</li>
                        <li class="plan-button"><a href="#">Get Started &raquo;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Table end -->
            </div>
            <!-- Account 0€ -->
        </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
// Prebuild colors
@white      : #ffffff;
@dark       : #4a4a4a;
@blue       : #4e94c9;
@blue-dark  : #2279bc;
@blue-font  : #276db3;
@purple     : #805ca2;
@purple-dark: #5b308d;
@gray-light : #a8a8a8;
@gray-font  : #797979;
@pink       : #bf4194;
@pink-light : #F04;

// Other
@letter-spacing:(2px);
.bold  { font-weight: 700}
.hr {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 4px;
    background: url("../images/hr.gif") no-repeat center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
// Pricing section -3
.pricing  {
    padding: 100px 0;
    h2 {
        letter-spacing: @letter-spacing;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: @blue-font;
        .bold {
            color: @purple-dark;
        }
    }
    // Price table switcher
    .table-switcher {
        text-align: center;
        input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .btn-switch,
        input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + .cd-switch{
            /* Safary bug fix selector */
            -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
            -moz-transform: translateX(120px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
            -o-transform: translateX(120px);
            transform: translateX(120px);
            background: @blue-font;
        }
        .fieldset {
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0px 2px;
            border-radius: 50em;
            border: 1px solid @gray-light;
            input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
                color: @white;
                transition: all 0.5s;
            }
        }
        input[type="radio"] {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        label {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 120px;
            height: 39px;
            line-height: 45px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.4rem;
        }
        .btn-switch {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            left: 2px;
            height: 40px;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: @purple-dark;
            border-radius: 50em;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
            transition: transform 0.5s;

        }
    }
    .no-js .table-switcher {
        display: none;
    }
    // Table info
    // Popover box
    .arrow_box {
        position: relative;
        background: @purple;
        border: 3px solid @purple-dark;
        padding: 15px;
        color: @white;
    }
    .arrow_box{
        &:after {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:before {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
    .arrow_box {
        &:before{
            border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
            border-top-color: @purple-dark;
            border-width: 10px;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }
        &:after {
            border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
            border-top-color: @purple-dark;
            border-width: 10px;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }
    }
    // Accounts
    .accounts {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .top-tooltip{
        background-color: #26c07d;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin:-87px auto 68px;
        padding: 6px;
        color:#fff;
        width:80px;

    }
    .price-table {
        width: 100%;
        .account-1 {

            .col-md-6 {
                padding: 0;
                left: 0;

            }
        }
    }
    .best-value{
        padding: 87px 0 72px !important;

    }
    .small-boxes {
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding-top: 72px;
        padding-bottom: 68px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .plan {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #79a5b3;
        line-height:30px;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .plan-cost {
        font-size:60px !important;
        color:#000 !important;
        line-height:90px !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .plan-duration {
        line-height: 30px !important;
        margin-bottom:35px;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .plan-button {
        border: none !important;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .plan-button-big {
        border: none !important;
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
    .price-table ul li {
        color: #a2a4a6;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-bottom: #f2f4f5 1px solid;
        border-top: #f2f4f5 1px solid;
        line-height: 47px;
    }
    .price-table ul li a{
        background-color:#FFF;
        border: #d4d7d9 1px solid;
        padding: 15px 30px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:#27b0d8;
        font-weight:400;
        text-decoration:none;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .price-table ul li a:hover{
        background-color:#44bbdd;
        border: #44bbdd 1px solid;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .price-table ul li a.big{
        background-color:#ec4f4f;
        border: #ec4f4f 1px solid;
        padding: 15px 30px;
        font-size: 24px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:400;
        text-decoration:none;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .price-table ul li a.big:hover{
        background-color:#293340;
        border: #293340 1px solid;
        color:#fff;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.account-2').hide();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="duration"]').click(function () {
        $('.account-1').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.account-2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('input[name="duration"]').click(function () {
        $('.account-2').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.account-1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwmBLE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script... [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmoGVX)

```
     $('.account-2').hide();
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var flagcheck= false;
            $('input[name="duration"]').click(function () {     
            if(flagcheck==false){
                $('.account-1').fadeOut('slow');
                $('.account-2').fadeIn('slow');
                flagcheck=true; 
            }else{
                $('.account-2').fadeOut('slow');
                $('.account-1').fadeIn('slow');                 
                flagcheck= false;
             }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working as you are using same trigger to do the same thing. Use

```
this.val()
```

to target your content that you want to display.

**UPDATED:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[name="duration"]').click(function () {
        $objToHide = "";
        $('.account-box').each(function(){//find out which obj is visible here
            if ($(this).css("display") == "block"){
                $objToHide = $(this);
            }
        });
        var content = $(this).val()
        $objToHide.fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $("."+content).fadeIn('slow')
        });
    });

});
```

Try above now, with this one you will find the visible element first and fade it out, when the fadeOut event will be done the other element will fade in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The overlap not working correctly, the second content is loaded from the bottom and bounces